# Google App Engine: 404 Not Found with Custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I setup a Flask app on Google App Engine as a Flex project. 
When I browse to https://{project-id}.appspot.com everything is working fine and I can use the app without a problem. Why am I getting a 404?

**I setup a custom domain as host.mydomain.io**

> gcloud beta app domain-mappings list

```
ID                     SSL_CERTIFICATE_ID  SSL_MANAGEMENT_TYPE  
host.mydomain.io       5270000             AUTOMATIC
```

**Then I setup my dns to point to ghs.googlehosted.com**

> nslookup host.mydomain.io

```
Non-authoritative answer:
host.mydomain.io    canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com.
Name:   ghs.googlehosted.com
Address: 172.217.0.115
```

**However I always get a 404 and here are the logs**

> gcloud app logs tail -s default

```
2018-01-25 03:06:32 default[20180124t211951]  "GET /" 404
2018-01-25 03:06:36 default[20180124t211951]  "GET /" 404
```

**Yet when I browse using the https://{project-id}.appspot.com address it works fine**

```
2018-01-25 02:31:55 default[20180124t211951]  "GET /" 200
```

**app.yaml**

```
entrypoint: 'gunicorn manage:app -w 4 -b :$PORT'
env: flex
runtime: python
env_variables:
  FLASK_CONFIG: "production"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was coming from my Flask configuration and not from Google App Engine

In my Production configuration I had this:

```
SERVER_NAME = "{project-id}.appspot.com"
```

This was causing Flask to return the 404 , not App Engine.

Changing it to

```
SERVER_NAME = "hostname.mydomain.io"
```

Fixed it for me.